# Where do i see Python print function output

Tags: python-3.x, azure-web-app-service

I am using azure web services, for my Python Django web app , where can i see 
the output of :
print ("strating "+str(datetime.now()))

Thanks,

Nir

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) out to see if there is any output there? Otherwise you'll likely need to direct where the output is placed, such as a blob storage account.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the print function in an Azure Functions app written in Python can be seen in the Azure portal in the "Monitor" section of the function app.

Then if you choose the "Logs" tab and "Filesystem Logs" (instead of default "App Insights Logs") there you can look up your "prints".
[here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NNSz.jpg)